# How correctly copy and modify an array in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to copy an array, replace some elements in it and then replace the original array with the copy containing the new elements.

Here's my code:

```
type Span = {
  start: number
  end: number
}

const handleSplitClick = (span: Span, tag: string) => {
    let copy = props.value.map(a => {return{...a}})
    const splitIndex = copy.findIndex(s => s.start === span.start && s.end === span.end)
    if (splitIndex != -1 ){
      const tagIndex = (copy[splitIndex] as any).tags.findIndex((t:string) => t == tag)

      if (tagIndex > -1){
        (copy[splitIndex] as any).tags.splice(tagIndex, 1)
        console.log(copy)
        console.log(props.value)
      }
    }
 }
```

Here's how `props.value` looks:

[image: props.value]

I'm trying to modify the tags array within props.value.

I tried to initialise the copy of the array in these ways:

```
//1
let copy = props.value.map(a => {return{...a}})

//2 
let copy = [...props.value]

//3 
let copy = props.value.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
```

Regardless of what I do, when I try to remove the particular element from tags:

```
(copy[splitIndex] as any).tags.splice(tagIndex, 1)
```

Both the original `props.value` and `copy` get modified.

How can I correctly achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"Here's how props.value looks:"*  Please post code, error messages, markup, **data structures**, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a new array where you've removed the matching tag from the `tags` array when its `start` and `end` match, and that you want to do this immutably (that is, **without** changing the original array or original element object, like a state update in React and similar). To do that, in `map` return the other elements unchanged, and return a new element with the updated `tags` for the one that matches:

```
const handleSplitClick = (span: Span, tag: string) => {
    // Use `map` to create the new array
    const copy = props.value.map((element) => {
        // Is this the element we want to update?
        if (element.start === span.start && element.end === span.end) {
            // Yes, return an updated copy with the first tag removed
            return {
                ...element,
                tags: element.tags.filter((t) => t !== tag),
            };
        }
        // No, just return the element unchanged
        return element;
    });
    // ...use or return `copy`...
};
```

Or if you prefer keeping things really terse:

```
const handleSplitClick2 = (span: Span, tag: string) => {
    // Use `map` to create the new array
    const copy = props.value.map((element) =>
        element.start === span.start && element.end === span.end
            ? {
                  ...element,
                  tags: element.tags.filter((t) => t !== tag),
              }
            : element
    );
    // ...use or return `copy`...
};
```

Note that in the vast majority of cases, you don't need or want type annotations on the callback parameters for `map` or `filter`; TypeScript will infer them correctly:

Live version with TypeScript commented out:

```js
const props = {
    value: [
        {start: 0, end: 1, tags: ["a", "b", "c"]},
        {start: 1, end: 2, tags: ["a", "b", "c"]},
        //                             ^^^ The one we'll target
        {start: 2, end: 3, tags: ["b", "c"]},
    ]
}

const handleSplitClick = (span/*: Span*/, tag/*: string*/) => {
    // Use `map` to create the new array
    const copy = props.value.map((element) => {
        // Is this the element we want to update?
        if (element.start === span.start && element.end === span.end) {
            // Yes, return an updated copy with the first tag removed
            return {
                ...element,
                tags: element.tags.filter((t) => t !== tag),
            };
        }
        // No, just return the element unchanged
        return element;
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(copy, null, 4));
};

handleSplitClick({start: 1, end: 2}, "b");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```